# Problem with ArrayAdapter<String> i can't show data from String []

Tags: android, android-layout

First thanks in advance for any help.

I got not exception in this code but for any reason i can't show the list of the data .

from my activity

```
ListView mRemindersList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_reminders);
String[] mTimes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.eventTimes);

mRemindersList.setAdapter(new ReminderAdapter(this,
    R.layout.reminders_list, mTimes));
```

my data called evenTimes ( R.array.eventTimes )

```
<string-array name="eventTimes">
    <item name="None">None</item>
    <item name="5m">5 minutes before</item>
    <item name="15m">15 minutes before</item>
    <item name="30m">30 minutes before</item>
    <item name="1h">1 hour before</item>
    <item name="2h">2 hour before</item>
    <item name="1d">1 day before</item>
</string-array>
```

this is my adapter which is a nested class in my activity

```
private class ReminderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private int resId;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param resource
     * @param objects
     */
    public ReminderAdapter(Context context, int resId, String[] objects) {
        super(context, resId, objects);
        this.resId = resId;
        this.mInflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.items = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        TextView remider = null;

      if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(resId, parent, false);

        remider = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.reminder);
        }

        String time = (String) getItem(position);
        remider.setText(time);

        return convertView;

    }
 }
```

and this is the textview with the data.

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/reminder" android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="30dip"
     android:textColor="#000000"
     android:singleLine="true" />
```

any advice.

Cheers Ron

Answer (score 0):

When your convert view is not null, you are not getting `remider` so this may be null in the call to `remider.setText(time);` and the `getView()` method will fail with a NPE.

Have a look at the docs for a correct implementation of the view holder pattern (e.g. in [this example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html) ; I can't find the article that explains this atm)..

Comment: Hi Heiko, what i said i dont any npe and also every time my convertview is null and my reminder textview has data the thing is for any reason i cant show the data, thanks anyways